# Как сделать бота на Python для чтения закрепленных сообщений в Telegram

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, бот, telebot

Пришел сюда потому что не смог найти информацию о том, как "спарсить"
закрепленное сообщение в Telegram. Пробовал библиотеки telebot и telegram, telegram.ext, но не нашел информацию о них.

Вопрос: Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Установка библиотеки `python-telegram-bot` 
   `pip install python-telegram-bot --upgrade`
2. Создание стандартного бота:

```
from telegram import Update, ForceReply
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, CallbackContext

updater = Updater(token='TOKEN', use_context=True)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

def start(update, context):
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="Hello, World!")

start_handler = CommandHandler('start', start)
dispatcher.add_handler(start_handler)

updater.start_polling()
```

3. Добавляем `echo`-функцию, для того, чтобы протестировать получение объекта чата:

```
def echo(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    print(context.bot.get_chat(ID).pinned_message)

dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, echo))
```

4. Вставляем `ID` чата, в котором есть бот и из которого нам нужно получить закреплённое сообщение.
5. Запускаем бота и пишем ему любое сообщение.
6. Готово. В консоли бот запринтит объект закреплённого сообщения.

Библиотека: https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot 
Документация к библиотеке: https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ 
Документация Telegram API: https://core.telegram.org/bots/

Comment: Спасибо, но значение на выходе получается None

Comment: Проблема уже скорее в самой библиотеке, почитай документацию, я думаю там что-то про это есть.

Comment: Ок, спасибо вам